# code which can run on dot net and xamarin for bitmap image

Tags: xamarin

I have a dot net dll which uses System.Drawing.dll for using classes like Bitmap, Rectangle,Size etc.. But my dll cannot be used on xamarin... Plz suggest me what else should I use in my dot net dll for using Bitmap etc.so that it can run on xamarin.

Comment: What you are trying to do is platform specific, therefore a Bitmap doesn't exist as it uses the device to create the context. Android is Bitmap, ios is UIImage, and windows mobile is Bitmap. All of them are different.

Answer (score 0):

Your dot net dll is complied for specified platform, such as Windows. so you cannot use it in other phone OS. It is no way for you to directly use dll in Xamarin unless you build it for portable class. But portable class is a generic class base, it lack of lots of classes. Such as Bitmap, it is different in different OS like Nick Turner said, so you will failed to build your source file.
The best way, you can reuse some none-platform dependent code in you dll, but for others, you need to write new code in each Android, ios, winphone project.  So the Xamarin is not so wonderful for writing once, using every where. There is still lots of work in Xamarin, especially for platform specific code.